# File I/O in C++ - Having some trouble writing back data?

Tags: c++, file, file-io

This project is a basic ATM program. I'm using a file to store all the account details. So, every time I run the .exe file, It will read the data from the file and insert it into an AVL tree. And when I close the program, all the data in the AVL nodes will be inserted back into the file.

Data is stored in the file in this order (Each separated by a newline char) ID, Password, Name, Add, City, Pin, Balance. 
Sample file --

```
12
4576 
Vert 
No_999,GoLane 
Dallas 
89777 
50000 
16 
2342 
Nerd 
No_888,FoLane 
Chicago 
89999 
30000
```

The problem is I cannot write back data into the file. Any suggestions please?
P.S. Please excuse my inline class methods please...
Program--

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

fstream file("one2.txt",ios::in|ios::out);//Opening the file 'one2.txt' in global scope

//AVL tree code starts here

class avl
{
  struct node //The structure node which is going to hold the data sets in the tree
  {
     int id,pwd;
     char name[15],add[30],city[10];
     int pn;
     double bal;

     node *left, *right;
     int height;
     //node constructors
     node(int i,int p,char nam[15], char a[30], char c[10],int pin,double b, node * l,node * r,int h)
     {
              id=i;
              pwd=p;
              strcpy(name,nam);
              strcpy(add,a);
              strcpy(city,c);
              pn=pin;
              bal=b;
              left=l;
              right=r;
              height=h;
     }
     node()
     {
           left=right=NULL;
           id=pwd=pn=0;
           bal=0;
           height=-1;
     }
 };
 node *root;
 node *nullnode;

 int Height(node *t)const //Func to return the height of a node
 {
  return((t==NULL)? -1:t->height);
  }

 int max(int a,int b)
 {
  return(a>b)?a:b;
  }

  //Beginning of Insert() -- To create and insert data into the nodes 
  void insert(const int &x,int p, char nam[15], char a[30], char c[10],int pin,double b, node *&t)
  {
    if(t==NULL)
        t = new node(x,p,nam,a,c,pin,b,NULL,NULL,-1);
    else if(x<t->id)
    {
      insert(x,p,nam,a,c,pin,b,t->left);
      if(Height(t->left) - Height(t->right)==2)
      {
                     if(x<t->left->id)
                            single_rotate_with_left(t);
                     else
                         double_rotate_with_left(t);
      }
     }

     else if(x>t->id)
     {
       insert(x,p,nam,a,c,pin,b,t->right);
       if(Height(t->right)-Height(t->left)==2)
       {
              if(x>t->right->id)
                   single_rotate_with_right(t);
              else
                  double_rotate_with_right(t);
       }
     }
    else
       t->height=max(Height(t->left),Height(t->right)+1);
 }
 //End of insert()

 //Func to print the node data. Just a sample to check if all the data
 // were inserted into the tree
 //Inorder traversal 
 void print(node *&t)
 {
   if(t!=NULL)
   {
       print(t->left);
       cout<<endl;
       cout<<"ID "<<t->id<<" Name "<<t->name;
       cout<<endl<<t->pwd<<endl<<t->add<<"\n"<<t->city;
       cout<<"-"<<t->pn<<endl<<t->bal<<endl;
       print(t->right);
   }
 }

  //Think there's gonna be no problem with the rotation and other AVL tree func codes.
  //Beginning of AVL rotations 
  void single_rotate_with_left(node *&k2)
  {
     node *k1=k2->left;
     k2->left=k1->right;
     k1->right=k2;
     k2->height=max(Height(k2->right),Height(k2->left))+1;
     k1->height=max(Height(k1->left),(k2->height))+1;
     k1=k2;
  }
  void single_rotate_with_right(node *&k2)
  {
   node *k1=k2->right;
   k2->right=k1->left;
   k1->left=k2;
   k2->height=max(Height(k2->left),Height(k2->right))+1;
   k1->height=max(Height(k1->right),(k2->height))+1;
   k1=k2;
  }
   void double_rotate_with_left(node *&a)
  {
    single_rotate_with_right(a->left);
   single_rotate_with_left(a);
  }
 void double_rotate_with_right(node *&a)
 {
   single_rotate_with_left(a->right);
   single_rotate_with_right(a);
 }

 //End of AVL rotations

 //Function to return the node. The 'id' variable to be searched is passed as a param 
 node*& search(int x,node *&t)
 {

      if(t->id>x)
           return search(x,t->left);
      else if(t->id<x)
           return search(x,t->right);
      else if(t->id==x)
          {
              return t;
          }
      else
                  return nullnode;
 }
 //End of search. I'm using this in the loadnode() function.

 //This is where I try to write data back into the file.
 void update1(node *&t,int x) // x is the control variable
 {
   if(x==1)
   //This block will be executed only once when the function is called for the
   //first time. Used to seek to the beginning of the file
   {
          file.seekg(0,ios::beg);
          x++;
   }
   if(t!=NULL)// Inorder traversal in the tree
   {

             update1(t->left,x);

             //writing the data in the same order as it was stored. 
             file<<t->id<<endl;
             file<<t->pwd<<endl;
             file<<t->name<<endl;
             file<<t->add<<endl;
             file<<t->city<<endl;
             file<<t->pn<<endl;
             file<<t->bal<<endl;

             update1(t->right,x);
   }              
 }

 public:
     //Avl Constructor - This one is the one which is actually used.
     avl(int x,int p,char nam[15], char a[30], char c[10],int pin,double b)
     {
          root= new node(x,p,nam,a,c,pin,b,NULL,NULL,-1);
          nullnode=new node;
     }
     avl()
     {
          root->left=root->right=NULL;
          root->height=-1;
     }

     //Call to the private insert function
     void insert1(const int &x,int p,char nam[15], char a[30], char c[10],int pin,double b)
     {
          insert(x,p,nam,a,c,pin,b,root);
     }
     //Call to the private print() function
     void display()
     {
          cout<<endl;
          print(root);
     }



     //Function to write a new value for 'bal' variable to a node.
     //I'm actually using this to update a node anconfirm whether the value of the updated node 
     //is reflected back at the node 
     void loadnode(int x)
     {
          node *&t=search(x,root);
          cout<<"\nLoaded node...\n";
          cout<<t->id;
          cout<<" "<<t->name;
          t->bal=40000;
          cout<<"\nUpdated Bal.."<<t->bal;
     }



     void update()
     {
          //file.seekp(0);
          update1(root,1);
     }

};//End of AVL Class



main()
{ 

 cout<<"The output..\n";
 int i, p, pn;
 char n[15],a[30],c[10];
 double b;
 int prev_id=0;




 file>>i>>p>>n>>a>>c>>pn>>b;
 prev_id=i;
 avl list(i,p,n,a,c,pn,b);
 while(file)
  {

        file>>i>>p>>n>>a>>c>>pn>>b;
        if(prev_id!=i)
        // I'm using this because i got a weird scenario in which the last record was repeated twice.
        {

        list.insert1(i,p,n,a,c,pn,b);
        }
        prev_id=i;
  }



  cout<<endl<<"The elements in AVL tree are...\n\n";
  list.display();
  list.loadnode(12);//12 is the id i used for one of my records.
  //Calling to write back the data into the file.
  list.update();

  file.close();
  getch();
  return 0;
}

//End of program
```

Comment: What happens, or more specifically, what doesn't happen that you expect to?

Comment: @chad When i'm trying to write the data back into the file using the update() function, the change is not reflecting in the file.

Comment: @Ganz7 Try checking file.is_open() and file.good() return true. Maybe the file failed to open or some error happened before you started writing to it.

Comment: @selalerer Yes! When i use file.good() just before the update function it returns false!
But it returns true for the is_open function.
Anyway to solve this? Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If file.good() returned false, some previous operation on the file failed (maybe even a read operation) and raised one of the error flags of the file object. An ugly way to solve it is to use file.clear() which will clear the error flag and allow next actions to execute successfully. A better way to solve it will be to check after each operation if there's an error (file.good() is false) and understand why this operation fails and fix it.

Comment: Thank you! It works! I'l try to check what the real problem is and address it.

Answer (score 0):

call `seekp()` to move the write pointer to the begining of the stream (`fstream`). `seekg()` moves the get pointer - not going to help when writing...

Comment: Tried it. Still Not working. Or am i doing something else wrong?